# Maaser on Selling Previously Purchased Items

Tags: halacha, money, tzedakah-charity, transactions, maaser-tithes

Many times people buy things and then later resell them. Assuming no profit was made in this sale, is there an obligation to give Maaser on the newly acquired money?

Practical examples: eBay, college books, yard/garage sales.

Comment: Essentially, your question seems to be: "Does one have to pay maaser on items sold at a loss?", am I correct?

Comment: @HodofHod Yep. I suppose that's it assuming there are no other aspects to it.

Comment: I think that's probably it. If not for being sold at a loss, there would be no difference from regular business: buying and selling.

Comment: @HodofHod Actually, just a small correction: While it is being sold at a pure loss (i.e. Sold - Bought < 0) there was utility gained from the item itself before it was sold.

Comment: True [15 chars]

Answer (score 2):

Maasar is only given on profits.

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42869&st=&pgnum=73

http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39798&st=&pgnum=14

Comment: Could you please provide an English translation on those two sources?